# Visual C++: How to embed and display a compile time message in code?

Tags: visual-c++, preprocessor, message, directive

Is there a way to **embed** a message in code that is **displayed** during **compile-time** when that piece of code is being compiled? The messages are diagnostic in nature and should not modify or abort the compile process.

(Disclaimer: I know the answer to this question. I didn't find it asked on Stack Overflow and I think it would be an useful addition to the knowledge base here.)

Comment: If it's not really a question doesn't it suppose to be a community wiki?

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#User-defined_compilation_errors_and_warnings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#User-defined_compilation_errors_and_warnings)

Comment: No, it's been decreed before that self-answered questions are okay. This is a valid programming question. It hasn't been asked on SO before (apparently). Ergo it's okay.

Comment: No, I think it's a real question.  Just because he already knows the answer doesn't mean it's Community Wiki.  Ashwin, if you have an answer, you should go ahead and just post it, unless someone already did.

Comment: Andy: I had done that (answered my own Q) a few times and got some flak from other SO folks for that ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
#pragma message("Your Message Here")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2.aspx